# WebRTC chrome : Failed to set local audio description recv parameters for m-section with mid='0'

Tags: webrtc

I am having an issue when toggling between on hold (pause/resume) between caller and callee. I sporadically having an issue with the following exception thrown:

```
Failed to set local answer sdp: Failed to set local audio description recv parameters for m-section with mid='0'.
```

The SDP that was sent is as following:

```
    o=- 8123285721396425994 20 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
    s=-
    t=0 0
    a=msid-semantic: WMS kHvO0o2GzTec38omRFi13PpLslU1lcJpY6h1
    m=audio 6577 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 9 113 (28 more lines)
    c=IN IP4 62.216.203.43
    a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
    a=candidate:2140827935 1 udp 2122260223 10.8.74.108 64763 typ host generation 0 network-id 1 network-cost 50
    a=candidate:411095253 1 udp 2122194687 172.19.64.1 64764 typ host generation 0 network-id 2
    a=candidate:4031697573 1 udp 2122131711 2001:a61:522:3401:641d:31e2:98ce:ff45 64765 typ host generation 0 network-id 4 network-cost 10
    a=candidate:3689448742 1 udp 2122066175 2001:a61:522:3401:f880:8764:be56:a574 64766 typ host generation 0 network-id 5 network-cost 10
    a=candidate:4036240074 1 udp 2121998079 192.168.178.30 64767 typ host generation 0 network-id 3 network-cost 10
    a=candidate:1008278873 1 udp 1685790463 62.216.203.43 6577 typ srflx raddr 192.168.178.30 rport 64767 generation 0 network-id 3 network-cost 10
    a=candidate:823758319 1 tcp 1518280447 10.8.74.108 9 typ host tcptype active generation 0 network-id 1 network-cost 50
    a=candidate:1443048485 1 tcp 1518214911 172.19.64.1 9 typ host tcptype active generation 0 network-id 2
    a=candidate:3201117781 1 tcp 1518151935 2001:a61:522:3401:641d:31e2:98ce:ff45 9 typ host tcptype active generation 0 network-id 4 network-cost 10
    a=candidate:2506848726 1 tcp 1518086399 2001:a61:522:3401:f880:8764:be56:a574 9 typ host tcptype active generation 0 network-id 5 network-cost 10
    a=candidate:3189235258 1 tcp 1518018303 192.168.178.30 9 typ host tcptype active generation 0 network-id 3 network-cost 10
    a=ice-ufrag:S96Y
    a=ice-pwd:tpc0ST0C8afqjZ5YaGD1G73O
    a=ice-options:trickle
    a=fingerprint:sha-256 93:9E:87:FA:4D:4F:A1:21:06:1C:45:D7:9B:18:85:DF:47:89:9F:AE:FB:C6:1E:2F:3E:01:9A:59:4F:BB:25:14
    a=setup:active
    a=mid:0
    a=sendrecv
    a=msid:kHvO0o2GzTec38omRFi13PpLslU1lcJpY6h1 3a1d3487-2efd-4eca-83a7-9a8ff584169e
    a=rtcp-mux
    a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000
    a=rtpmap:113 telephone-event/8000
    a=ssrc:2629658636 cname:EBgjrnnDur5zui0v
    a=ssrc:2629658636 msid:kHvO0o2GzTec38omRFi13PpLslU1lcJpY6h1 3a1d3487-2efd-4eca-83a7-9a8ff584169e
    a=ssrc:2629658636 mslabel:kHvO0o2GzTec38omRFi13PpLslU1lcJpY6h1
    a=ssrc:2629658636 label:3a1d3487-2efd-4eca-83a7-9a8ff584169e
```

I checked that for

> m=audio 6577 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 9 126 (28 more lines)

this would also work

Does anyone know why the offer is not working for chrome, but it's fine for firefox and safari?